# Java 8 Map: filter value and throw exception if match found

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to find a matching value in a Map and if found, I need to throw an IllegalArgumentException. My code is as follows:

```
final String stringToBeMatched = "someRandomString"; 

map.values()
   .stream()
   .filter(a -> stringToBeMatched == a.getField())
   .findAny()
   .ifPresent(a -> throw new IllegalArgumentException());
```

I get a syntax error on token "throw". I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Add a block around it.

Comment: `ifPresent(a -> { throw new IllegalArgumentException() })`

Comment: @khelwood: `ifPresent(a -> { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); })`

Answer (score 32):

A [lambda body can be an expression or a block of statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2).  However,

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException()
```

is a statement, which is neither.  Make it a block by surrounding it with braces.

```
.ifPresent(a -> {throw new IllegalArgumentException(); } );
```

And for your next question, [compare your string values with `.equals`, not with `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 4):

Alternate cleaner solution, using [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
boolean found = map.values()
                   .stream()
                   .anyMatch(a -> stringToBeMatched.equals(a.getField()));
if(found) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: If you're going to write additional code outside the loop, why not just make a function that raises the exception?

Answer (score 2):

findAny return a Optional, you can use orElseThrow

```
map.values()
   .stream()
   .filter(a -> stringToBeMatched == a.getField())
   .findAny()
   .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException());
```

Comment: The OP wanted to throw an Exception, if a match is found: Your solution throws an Exception, when no match is found.